# How do I rebind jQuery DataTable when the table is auto refreshed by background process

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table that I build with data coming from MySQL via PHP code and binding it to DataTable, the table and DataTable work just fine, but I have added a delete button for the table row, when I click that it calls a backend PHP which deletes the record than I am calling a new PHP to query the DB and build a new table and push it back onto the page, all works fine, EXCEPT that when the new query is formatted and pushed onto the age the dataTable is not binding at all, here is my Script.

Thanks

```
function aa_userDeleteSkill(in_id, in_uid) {
    $.ajax( {
        url: "user_delete_skill.php",
        type: "get", //send it through get method
        data: {
            id: in_id,
            uid: in_uid
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log( "success -- delete: " + response );

            // cleanup
            if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#SkillsUser' ) ) {
                $('#SkillsUser').DataTable().destroy();
            }
            $('#SkillsUser tbody').empty();

            // call the rendering function
            aa_userSkillRender( in_uid );

            jQuery('#SkillsUser').dataTable({
                "pageLength": 10,
                "ordering": false,
                "responsive": true,
                "destroy": true,
                drawCallback: function(dt) {
                    //console.log("draw() callback; initializing Select2's.");
                    //$('.experience-jquerySelect2-tag').select2({tags: true, width: "6em"});
                }
            });

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log( "failed -- delete: " + xhr );
        }
    } );
} // end of fucntion

function aa_userSkillRender( uid ) {
    // The following will prevent all future AJAX requests from being cached, 
    // regardless of which jQuery method you use ($.get, $.ajax, etc.)
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    // call the backend service 
    $("#IDuserListSkills").load("./user_render_skill.php?id=" + uid + " #IDuserListSkillsReturned",
        function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
            console.log("responseTxt: " + responseTxt);
            if (statusTxt == "success") {
                console.log("user_render_skill.php: External content loaded successfully!");
            }
            if (statusTxt == "error") {
                console.log("user_render_skill.php -- Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    );

} // end of fucntion
```

Comment: Things would have been much simpler if you used DataTables option [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) rather than reinventing that feature yourself.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I wish the table data was that simple, however during the PHP operation, I am adding new first column where there is a delete icon, then I am adding javascrip:xxxxxx notation to that cell with a specific UID and reference_id so the delete operation can work, later on I have to add code to generate unique cell ID for each cell etc...  the JSON_OBJECT MySQL and ajax feature of dataTable would have worked if I was not adding these other extra stuff to each row.

Comment: Above features can be achieved easily with DataTables options and API methods (moreover, I have posted on SO code snippets for that). Furthermore, I'm pretty sure some of those you don't even need to do to implement features you do this for.

Comment: U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg can you provide a link to the code snippets please?

Comment: If you have time and will to rebuild your app you may post separate questions to address one issue at a time and I'll be glad to answer them one by one. Otherwise, you may browse through the answers I have posted up until now and find many solutions to the problems similar to yours.

Comment: I solved my problem, my issue was I was treating the ajax and jquery.load() calls as synchronous operation and calling them in sequence,  once I placed my coeds inside the call-back functions, all worked fine.

Comment: As being said `ajax` option would solve your issue. The fact that you've found the workaround this time doesn't mean you solved the root cause of the issue. With that you may progress to the point where you'll need some feature or big fix that'll require API methods which will not work properly in such app structure.

Comment: To see how overcomplicated your approach is, just think of such thing - in order to delete your row from both server side storage and current view it is not even necessary to load your entire dataset (without deleted line) destroy your table,  and rebuild everything from scratch. You could have simply drop that line from your current view upon successful AJAX-call or, if it is really that important to refresh your table at this exact moment, invoke `.ajax.reload()` without destroying everything.